# 405 Method Not Allowed when using headers in the fetch api

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, .htaccess

I am trying to Make an ajax request using `fetch`, and when I do, I get a `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error.

I am executing it like this:

```
fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
        'Game-Token': '123'
    }
});
```

And that is giving me an error. If I remove the headers, the request goes through. However, I need that header for validation on the server.

```
fetch(url, { method: 'get' });
```

I have the following setup in my .htaccess file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, FETCH"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, Game-Token, developerKey"
Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Game-Token"
```

I am not sure what is causing this to not go through.

Comment: What URL are you sending your request to? Is it your own API, or third party? If it is the latter, do they provide documentation how to access the API?

Comment: It is my own API server that we run using lumen

Comment: Perhaps this is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622818/error-405-method-not-allowed-laravel-5

Comment: It looks like in `lumen` I need to catch the `OPTIONS` type in a route.

Comment: check your api method, it might be different that's why you getting this respone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this had nothing to do with `JavaScript` or the `.htaccess`. Instead it has to do with `Lumen`. We need to catch the `OPTIONS` request and reply back. What we did was create a middleware file that checked for the `OPTIONS` method and responds with a `200`.

```
use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            return response('',200);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```