# Laravel Delete not working

Tags: php, laravel, controller, eloquent, authorization

As the title suggests, I can't get the delete() option to work. I've struggled through a lot of posts online but the right answer just isn't there. 
I'm using Laravel 5.5 with Homestead (installed a week ago, newest versions or so).

Let me give you some code and I really hope somebody is able to help me out.

This gives me a headache and the olanzapine is running out. Please tell me what I am doing wrong, and if there is something that's missing, please let me know!

I want to delete a page as a admin, but I Laravel doesn't seem to authorize me and gives me this error:

```
    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

This is my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Auth;
use App\Page;
use App\Http\Requests\WorkWithPage;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('admin');
        $this->middleware('can:manageUsers,App\User');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()) {
            $pages = Page::paginate(20);
        } else {
            $page = Auth::user()->pages()->paginate(5);
        }
        return view('admin.pages.index', ['pages' => $pages]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('admin.pages.create')->with(['model' => new Page()]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(WorkWithPage $request)
    {
        Auth::user()->pages()->save(new Page($request->only([
            'title','url','content'])));

            return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Pagina succesvol aangemaakt');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)){
            return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Pagina succesvol aangepast');
        } 

        return view('admin.pages.edit', ['model' => $page]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(WorkWithPage $request, Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('update', $page)){
            return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Dat mag jij niet');
        } 

        $page->fill($request->only([
            'title','url','content'
        ]));

        $page->save();

        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Pagina succesvol aangepast');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Page $page)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->cant('delete', $page)){
            return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Hey knul! Pssst! Wegwezen!');
        }

        $page->id->delete();

        return redirect()->route('pages.index')->with('status', 'Page has been deleted.');
    }
}
```

And this is my index page (index as in admin index for backend :

```
 @extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
<div class="container">
    @if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
    @endif
    <a href="{{ route('pages.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Nieuwe pagina</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Naam</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Opties</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach($pages as $page)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('pages.edit', ['page' => $page->id]) }}">{{ $page->title }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ $page->url }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a href="{{ route('pages.destroy', ['page' => $page->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger delete-link" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this page?"
                    data-form="delete-form">
                    Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{$pages->links()}}
</div>
<form id="delete-form" action="" methode="POST">
        {{method_field('DELETE')}} 
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
    </form>
@endsection
```

Then there the routes:

```
   <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', function() {
    return view('admin.index');
})->middleware('admin');

Route::resource('/admin/pages', 'Admin\PagesController', ['except' => ['show']]);

Route::resource('/admin/blog', 'Admin\BlogController', ['except' => ['show']]);

Route::resource('/admin/users', 'Admin\UsersController', ['except' => ['create', 'store', '']]);

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Then the policy:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Page;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PagePolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before($user, $ability) {
        if ($user->isAdmin()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the page.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        return $user->id = $page->user_id;
    }

     /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the page.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Page  $page
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Page $page)
    {
        return $user->id = $page->user_id;
    }
}
```

And finally the middleware:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;

class AccessAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasAnyRole(['Super Admin','Admin'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('login');
    }
}
```

## Update: fixed!

In the view I changed:

```
            @foreach($model as $post)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ route('blog.edit', ['post' => $post->id]) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{ $post->user()->first()->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->slug }}</td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a href="{{ route('blog.destroy', ['blog' => $post->id])}}" class="btn btn-danger delete-link" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this page?"
                    data-form="delete-form">
                    Delete
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{$model->links()}}
</div>
<form id="delete-form" action="#" methode="POST">
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
</form>
```

To:

```
        @foreach($pages as $page)
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('pages.edit', ['page' => $page->id]) }}">{{ $page->title }}</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{ $page->url }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">
            <form action="{{ route('pages.destroy', ['page' => $page->id]) }}" method="POST" class="btn btn-danger delete-link" >
                <input type="submit" value="delete"/>
                {{method_field('DELETE')}} 
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
{{$pages->links()}}
```

Comment: Where is the delete route? Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622818/error-405-method-not-allowed-laravel-5

Comment: That;s the funny part; I followd some tutorials online and they knew how to do it without. I've been messing with routes, but without result. I both trying to learn PHP as Laravel at the same time so unable to actually understand the problem here (will be into PHP more then Laravel after I fixed this, fyi)

Comment: Other things that come to mind... POSTing to a GET route. Trust the logs, it's telling you the error.

Comment: Lack of routing seems to work fine for edit (and update). About the POST for GET part: that's told explicitly in the tut. So I went with that

Comment: Routes and ACL usually like things expressed explicitly. I'd focus there. This looks wrong. `['create', 'store', '']` Whats the empty string? And beating a dead horse... would expect something listing 'delete'...

Comment: `route('pages.create')` are you sure that's the correct name? Maybe its more like `route('/admin/pages.create')` ?

Comment: @apokryfos Works perfectly. Creating and editting work fine. It's only the delete part that doesnt work

Comment: You have the delete being called from an achor. That would do a `GET`  won't it? You should consider using a form and a link-like submit button to achieve the desired effect

Comment: @apokryfos I notice that this is getting abracadabra for me. I'll have to get some sleep to be able to understand that one.

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you very much! Your comment made me change some things and it works! I can't give you the correct answer, but I will post a update for anybody who stumbles into this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where to start...
First the exception you are receiving is because you are sending wrong method to the url. (I never do it that way) but probably you are sending GET when you are expecting POST (with DELETE overwrite). You have wrong named "methode", it should be "method".
Next... not sure if this is gone work `$page->id->delete();`... maybe `$page->delete()`.
As suggestion - maybe it will be better to use `!can()` instead of `cant()`. There is no difference, but `cant()` may confuse you in some point.
And I am glad to see someone using `->fill()` method but you may come up on a small problem when dealing with checkboxes. Check this: https://github.com/LaraModulus/admin-core/blob/master/src/traits/HelpersTrait.php

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fixed the 'methode' type (half Dutch, I feel like an idiot). Also I had it as $page->delete(); before I started messing. After reverting, nothing actually changed (still trying to translate the first part of your comment in noob-language).