# Laravel profile update error

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to duplicate profile page in Laravel. It's all works fine but when i click 'Save' to save changes in profile it show's me like

```
 /**
     * Throw a method not allowed HTTP exception.
     *
     * @param  array  $others
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
     */
    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
    }

    /**
     * Get routes from the collection by method.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $method
     * @return array
     */
    public function get($method = null)
    {
        return is_null($method) ? $this->getRoutes() : Arr::get($this->routes, $method, []);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the route collection contains a given named route.
```

With no Arguments. And this massage
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message.

From some reasons i can't import code from my file, can anyone help without code?

Comment: `when i click 'Save' to save changes in profile it show's me like` ... shows you what? The code you have included is not an error message.  Show us *exactly* what you see when you click save.

Answer (score 0):

The controller action you are trying to reach expects a certain HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc). A 405 means you have tried to access that endpoint via the wrong method.

Check your routuing config to see which method you should be calling. Here's an example asking for a DELETE method:

```
Route::delete('empresas/eliminar/{id}', [
        'as' => 'companiesDelete',
        'uses' => 'CompaniesController@delete'
]);
```

See this post: [Error 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622818/error-405-method-not-allowed-laravel-5)