# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on Post Method

Tags: php, laravel

Getting started with Laravel and I am encountering a problem when trying to post to one of my pages.

I am using Postman to create a post request to my /clock page.

The post is sending a simple Json with a single field:

[image: POST body]

Here are the Post's headers:

[image: POST headers]

My route is currently placed in the routes/api.php folder and contains the following:

```
<pre>
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
    |
    */

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request)                         {
        return $request->user();
    });
    Route::post('/json', 'FormController@post');
    Route::post('/clock', 'PayrollController@index');
```

The code for the controller it links to `app/Http/Controller/PayrollController.php` looks like this:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;


    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use App\Company;
    use Response;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class PayrollController extends Controller
    {

        function __construct()
        {
        }

        public function index()
        {
        }
```

When I execute the post in Postman this is the error I am getting:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException:  in file /var/www/html/oit_laravel1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 255
Stack trace:
  1. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException-&gt;() ...
```

Comment: Check your server logs. This looks like a postman error. Sometimes postman send get instead of post randomly. This would show up in your server logs. Also can you post the result of php artisan route:list ?

Comment: Also add a header in the tab next to the body with the key: Accept and the Value application/json

Comment: If you're defining the routes in api.php, Laravel is automatically prefixing them with /api.  Are you posting to /api/clock or just /clock?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 405 (Method Not Allowed) Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622818/error-405-method-not-allowed-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you define a post Route on a get Request, define your request to use post header, if using form, change method to post, if not querying the database, change your Route to

```
 Route::get('/clock', 'PayrollController@index');
```